# Implementing Lightbox in Magento

Tags: magento

I already have an existing page which I'm trying to turn into a Magento website. One the pages I'm working on makes use of Lightbox. I tried including the lightbox file through Design in the CMS Page. Same for content but it didn't work there. Is there any way I can include the lightbox javascript from the previous website without having to touch the xml, html and php files? How do I make the lightbox work on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a javascript file to the page's head by adding the following to the design tab of your CMS page (note that the path is relative to the root js directory). However, if you plan on using lightbox on multiple pages, this would not be the preferred method because you'd have to copy this into the design tab of every page you needed it on.

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><js>custom/lightboxjs</js></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: So basically all I have to do is put the file on my root js directory and add head on the reference tag? No wonder it wasn't working. I didn't put put the reference name at all. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yup, that will add the js sheet to your page. Make sure you also have jQuery loaded and that you add rel="lightbox" to the links of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

**View.PHTML**

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<?php $config = Mage::getStoreConfig('mdloption/product-type-option'); ?>
<?php if($config['product-view-option'] !=2 && $config['product-view-option'] !=3): ?>
    <?php $classnNum ='span9'?>
<?php else:?>
    <?php $classnNum ='f-fix'?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($config['product-view-option']==3):?>
    <?php $classnNum2 = 'left-carousel'?> 
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view <?php echo $classnNum; ?>">
<!--<a class="prePage" href="<?php //echo $_SESSION['core']['last_url'];?>"><?php //echo $this->__('Return to Previous Page')?></a>-->
 <!--Prev/Next Code Start-->
      <?php 
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$prev_url = $next_url = $url = $_product->getProductUrl();
if ($this->helper('catalog/data')->getCategory()) {
$category = $this->helper('catalog/data')->getCategory();
} else {
$_ccats = $this->helper('catalog/data')->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_ccats[0]);
}
$children = $category->getProductCollection();
$_count = is_array($children) ? count($children) : $children->count();
if ($_count) {
foreach ($children as $product) {
$plist[] = $product->getId();
}
$current_pid  = $this->helper('catalog/data')->getProduct()->getId();
$curpos   = array_search($current_pid, $plist);
$previd   = isset($plist[$curpos+1])? $plist[$curpos+1] : $current_pid;
$product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($previd);
$prevpos  = $curpos;
while (!$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
$prevpos += 1;
$nextid   = isset($plist[$prevpos])? $plist[$prevpos] : $current_pid;
$product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($nextid);
}
$prev_url = $product->getProductUrl();
$nextid   = isset($plist[$curpos-1])? $plist[$curpos-1] : $current_pid;
$product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($nextid);
$nextpos  = $curpos;
while (!$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
$nextpos -= 1;
$nextid   = isset($plist[$nextpos])? $plist[$nextpos] : $current_pid;
$product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($nextid);
}
$next_url = $product->getProductUrl();
}
?>    
      <!--Prev/Next Code End-->
  <div class="product-essential">
    <div class="product-img-box span6 <?php echo $classnNum2;?>"> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?> </div>
    <div class="productDetailBox span6">
             <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
      <div class="no-display">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field_1" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-shop">
        <div class="product_left f-fix">
       <div class="nextPre"> 
<!--          <a rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="<?php echo $this->__('No Products')?>" class="prod-prev disable" href="JavaScript:void(0);">Prev</a> 
          <a rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $this->__('No Products')?>" class="prod-next disable" href="JavaScript:void(0);">NEXT</a>-->
                       <?php if ($url <> $prev_url):?>
            <a class="prod-next" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $this->__('Volgende product')?>" href="<?php echo $prev_url; ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($url <> $next_url):?>
            <a  rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="<?php echo $this->__('Vorige product')?>" class="prod-prev" href="<?php echo $next_url; ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
          <div class="product-name">
            <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
         </div>   
         <div class="review"> <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?> </div>
            <div class="stock_box"> 
                <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
            <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Beschikbaar') ?></span></p>
            <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Verkocht') ?></span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <div class="short-description">
                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>

          <div class="pro-left">

            <div class="add_to_cart">
              <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
              <div class="add-to-box">
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                 <div class="price_box"> 
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?> 
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?> 
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml()?> 
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
              <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
              <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>

              <?php endif;?>
              <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
              <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
               <div class="price_box"> 
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?> 
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?> 
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml()?> 
                </div>
              <?php endif;?>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="f-fix">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
            <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
              <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
              <p class="email-friend"><a rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
              <?php endif; ?>
              <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
                    </div>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4f74bbe87b978120"></script>
              <!-- AddThis Button END -->
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('static_links')->toHtml() ?>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
        <div class="product-collateral" id="tabs"> 
             <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php if($config['product-view-option'] !=2 && $config['product-view-option'] !=3): ?>
<div class="product_right span3">
        <?php $config = Mage::getStoreConfig('mdloption/upsellsetting'); ?>
                <?php if($config['upsellblocks']==1):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products'); ?>
                <?php elseif($config['upsellblocks']==2):?>
                    <?php if($_product->getUpsellProducts()): ?>   
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products'); ?> 
                     <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('productBanner')->toHtml() ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product_custom_block')->toHtml() ?> 
                     <?php endif ?> 
                <?php elseif($config['upsellblocks']==3):?>
                      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products'); ?>
                     <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('productBanner')->toHtml() ?>
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product_custom_block')->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <div class="staticSidebar">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product-static-box')->toHtml() ?>
             </div>



</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products'); ?> 
<?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('related'); ?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
                hideOnContentClick  : true,
                showNavArrows       : false,
                arrows              : false,
                showTitle           : false,
                scrolling           : 'no', 
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            });




});
    </script>
```